# What percentage of vehicles has a speed between 92.7 km/h and 108.1 km/h?

Tags: normal-distribution

I know what equation to use, I'm just not sure how to apply it because there are particular units involved.

A traffic study has shown that vehicle speeds on a particular highway were normally distributed with a mean of 102.4 km/h and a standard deviation of 5.3 km/h. What percentage of vehicles has a speed between 92.7 km/h and 108.1 km/h?

Comment: Hint: z-scores.

Comment: do i have to convert anything because of the units?

Comment: Strangely enough, no. Units don't matter when you standardize.

Answer (score 0):

A normal distribution has density function
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-(x-\mu)^2/(2\sigma^2)}.$$
In your example with mean $\mu = 102.4$ and standard deviation $\sigma= 5.3$.

The proportion of vehicles with speed between $a$ and $b$ is then
$$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm d x,$$
so in your problem it is
$$\int_{92.7}^{108.1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\cdot 5.3^2}}e^{-(x-102.4)^2/(2\cdot 5.3^2)}\, \mathrm{d}x \approx 0.8253 = 82.53\%. $$

---

If the former approach was beyond what you've been taught at this moment, you may have been taught about $z$-scores, and then looking up the values in a table.

We calculate the $z$-values
$$z_1 = \frac{92.7-\mu}{\sigma} \approx -1.83019\quad\text{ and }\quad z_2 = \frac{108.1-\mu}{\sigma} \approx 1.07547. $$

Rounding we get $z_1 \approx -1.83$ and $z_2\approx 1.08$, and by looking up in a table for the standard normal cumulative density function we find
$$F(-1.83) = 0.0336\quad\text{ and }\quad F(1.08) = 0.8599. $$

The result (obviously an approximation since rounding have been used) is then given by
$$F(1.08)-F(-1.83) = 0.8599 - 0.0336 = 0.8263 = 82.63\%. $$

Comment: This appears beyond the OP's scope which is why I did not give the integral definition.

Comment: @SeanRoberson Perhaps you're right. I may add a little on how to solve it in another approach soon.